# Trying to construct a 3D object from a stack of 2D images in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, opengl, 3d, dicom

I have a stack of 2D dicom images and want to convert to a 3D object using VB.NET. I suppose I can solve it using openGL but any clue would help a lot. Do you know a free (or at least cheap) pack to do it? Would you help me to think my own solution. Thanks...

Comment: Like CT/MRI-style 3D reconstruction, or just a slice viewer?

Comment: 3d Reconstruction. Using the VTK suggested by Steve I could do it but when extracting skin I am still having a dirty. Then, the problem I am having now is to show only the bones. But I was pretty sucessfull reconstructing the 3D image from the DICOMs. BTW, I am developing using VB.NET.
As I am new here, is there a way (any action like voting) to say I appreciate his answer?

Comment: Nizam,  there should be a checkbox next to the answer that you should click on to "accept" the answer as valid.

Comment: Ok. I have already accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Visualization Toolkit](http://www.vtk.org/) to do this.  Although I haven't used it before, there is a .NET wrapper for VTK [here](http://vtkdotnet.sourceforge.net/).

If you want precompiled versions of these libraries, [ClearCanvas](http://www.clearcanvas.ca) has them checked into their repository.  [This](https://trac.clearcanvas.ca/source/wiki/GettingTheCode) page has instructions on accessing the ClearCanvas SVN repository.  The SVN folder where the files are contained is here:  svn://svn.clearcanvas.ca/source/Xian/Trunk/ReferencedAssemblies/Vtk

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Just one doubt: I need to convert the sequence of dcm files into a VTI file and, finally, show this file using the VTK control. Am I right?

Comment: The use of the VTK control as mentioned on the VTK for .NET page is not required, but this is probably the fastest way to get data displayed.  I would recommend starting this way.  I don't have any experience myself using VTK, but I know its widely used in the industry for 3D.

Comment: Steve. Thanks a lot!!! The VTK control is great and it seems it was suited for me ;-)